# CSS repeating-linear-gradient line width difference issue

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

Here is my linear-gradient on div, but the horizontal lines are not of same width

```css
.pattern1{
  height: 252px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, red 30px, transparent 0),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0 40px, black 0 42px)
}
```

```html
<div class='pattern1'></div>
```

What can we do to get line width constant. 
I am using chrome version 81.0.4044.138

[image: Screen shot also attached]

Comment: make sure you don't have any zoom level

Comment: Zoom is at 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different way. Maybe you won't have issue with it:

```css
.pattern1{
  height: 252px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, red 30px, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom, black 2px, transparent 0) top/ 1px 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class='pattern1'></div>
```